# Custom Android Lint for kotlin only (no java)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lint

I decided to write custom lint checks for Android and I have a strong belief in Android Lint, so I don't want to use `detekt` or `ktlint` for checking code (they can't parse xml files, etc and I'd like to use a single tool).

But when I've read docs for Android Lint, I found that they have this new `UAST` and `PSI` (`com.intellij.psi` package) stuff, when `detekt` uses its child (kotlin only `org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi`).

I don't have java code in my project and I'd like to write kotlin specific lint rules.

I see, that `com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Detector` has a method `createPsiVisitor` which returns `JavaElementVisitor`, and this `JavaElementVisitor` is subclass of `com.intellij.psi.PsiElementVisitor`. Is there any chance, that it's possible to use `org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor` instead?

Or how can I write kotlin specific checks in `Detector.UastScanner`?

I want (for example) to write rules for

> Kotlin hidden costs set of articles ([1](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/exploring-kotlins-hidden-costs-part-1-fbb9935d9b62), [2](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/exploring-kotlins-hidden-costs-part-2-324a4a50b70), [3](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/exploring-kotlins-hidden-costs-part-3-3bf6e0dbf0a4))

P.S. I succeeded in doing this in `detekt`, but I'd like to use default Android Lint.

**[UPD]** 
I found `com.android.tools.lint.checks.InteroperabilityDetector`. Probably it's possible to write kinda `KotlinVisitor` (as `JavaVisitor` in this class). And this `KotlinVisitor` will be just wrapper around `KtVisitor`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 3.4, the Kotlin PSI is available directly to custom lint checks (it's on the classpath).  When you're handed a UFile (the UAST abstraction on top of the Java and Kotlin AST's) it has a sourcePsi field which gives you the KtFile.

There's a "lint-dev" Google group you can read/join to discuss lint check development in more detail.

Comment: You mean 3.4 of the android gradle plugin?